# Should 'registerCustomer()' be in a Customer class or main/driver class

Tags: java, class, methods

Say I wanted to implement the following methods:

```
void registerCustomer();
void displayCustomer();
void editCustomer();
void deleteCustomer();
```

And say I have the following classes:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // put your stuff here
    }

    // void registerCustomer() { ... }
}
```

and

```
public class Customer {
    // data fields - id, name, etc
    // constructors, setters, getters

    // void registerCustomer() { ... }
}
```

Should I implement the methods in the `Main` class, or the `Customer` class?

I'm able to implement them either way without error. But which is the "better" way? How should I go about doing this?

Comment: There are good methodologies and approaches that make it easy to make such decisions. Look into domain-driven-design and similar systems. Here, this will essentially be collecting opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods that are to change or extract the state of a *single* Customer, it's name, phone number, id number,...., or that are part of a single Customer's innate behavior, should be part of the Customer class.

Methods that change the state of a collection of Customers -- adding a Custmoer, removing, selecting,... should be elsewhere, in its own class (or the main class, if that is the only other class).

so...

none of these are part of Customer itself since they appear to be working with a collection or grouping of Customer and don't focus on the state of a single Customer:

```
void registerCustomer();
void displayCustomer();
void editCustomer();
void deleteCustomer();
```

You might state that `editCustomer()` should be part of the Customer class since it appears to edit a single Customer, but I would argue that no, this appears to try to change the state of a selected Customer in a collection or GUI of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

These methods should be implemented somewhere else rather than the `Customer` class. I suggest you to create another class named `CustomerService` and make it implemenet the methods. Also, don't forget to provide parameters for your methods :)